# Float left div left and right div right in the header tag

Tags: html, css, alignment

Currently I'm trying to float a `<div>` to the left and a `<div>` to the right to separate the logo and the text within a shopping site for an assignment.

```
header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:left;
    font-size: larger;
    padding:5px;
}

.logo{
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

.headercatagories{
    float:right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

So far, the header appears stretched across (correctly)
The logo text appears to the left (correctly)
However, the categories div refuses to float to the right and remains to the left.

Comment: maybe post some html?

Answer (score 2):

First problem I see is you have two closing brackets after `.logo`. You should probably use a better IDE.

```css
header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:left;
    font-size: larger;
    padding:5px;
    height: 30px;
}

.logo{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

.headercatagories{
    float:right;
    text-align: right;
}

.headercatagories ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.headercatagories li{
    float:right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="headercatagories">
    <ul>
      <li>category 1</li>
      <li>category 2</li>
      <li>category 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Reason for this is poorly formulated and formatted questions. Keep it short and clean.

Comment: @Adam, I must say you're quite lucky to have such an answer without even posting your HTML code in the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
     // put ur left content
    </td>
    <td align="right">
    // ur right content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```